# Do something when request needs more time - how to do it?

Tags: javascript, request, fetch

I'm using a `fetch` to get some data from my API.

Is there a possibility to check if my request needs longer than 1000ms and than do something - like giving out a warning ***Attention request takes more time than excepted*** ?

I hope my question is clear - otherwise please come back to me !

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
  body: JSON.stringify(array),
})
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout`:

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(() => alert('More than 1000ms!'), 1001);

fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
  body: JSON.stringify(array),
})
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .finally(() => clearTimeout(timeout));
```